# get_user_meta and umeta_id

Tags: database, user-meta

```
function theme_achievements() {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();   
    if ( empty( $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if( $value >= '0' && $value <= '499' ) { 
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'author_level', array( 'lvl-0', '' ) );
    } elseif( $value >= '500' && $value <= '999' ) { 
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'author_level', array( 'lvl-1', '' ) );
    } else {
        ...
    }

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_achievements' );
```

With the function above I created an custom user meta_key (based on levels).

While looking inside my wp database (phpMyAdmin) to see if the meta_key is created and update properly, I noticed multiple `author_level` entries that keep increasing everything I load the page.

Inside the database `user_id`, `meta_key`, and `meta_value` are all the same but each entry has an unique `umeta_id`. Is this normal? I prefer to have just one entry per user to keep the database "clean".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this in 1 of 2 ways:

1. change the call to `add_user_meta()` to `update_user_meta()` when your 1st conditional evals to true.  As explained in [update_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/), "If the meta field for the user does not exist, it will be added."
2. pass `true` as the `$unique` (4th) param to `add_user_meta()`.  As explained in [add_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/), the `$unique` param controls "whether the same key should not be added" (i.e., when true, if the meta already exists, another one will **not** be added; it defaults to false).

In most cases, which is preferred comes down to "style".

**Edit**

The same applies to `add_post_meta()` vs `update_post_meta()` and `add_term_meta()` vs `update_post_meta()`.

Where #1 or #2 matters is if you've hooked into [update_{$meta_type}_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_meta_type_meta/) and expect it to always fire.  In case #1 (i.e., always use `update_user_meta()`) the `update_user_meta` action will **not** fire if the meta does not already exist, since `update_user_meta()` will simply call `add_user_meta()` if the meta doesn't ready exist.

Hence, if you care about capturing meta additions, you should generally hook into both `update_{$meta_type}_meta` *and* [add_{$meta_type}_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_meta_type_meta/), even if you always use `update_user_meta()`.

Comment: So instead of using `wp_head`, it's better to use `add_action( 'updated_user_meta', 'my_update_user_meta', 10, 4 );`?

Comment: @kiarashi sorry, I didn't see your comment until now.  No, you should be using the function `update_user_meta()`, not the filter.  The reason I added the discussion on the filters was that **IF** you hooked into the `update_user_meta` action and expected it to be fired the first time `update_user_meta()` was called you'd be disappointed...you have to hook into `add_user_meta` action as well.  But you don't **need** to hook into either of those actions...that discussion only applies **IF** you hook into ...